# how can I pass a C# component from one gameobject to another in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a C# script, called `A`. `A` are many variable. I put it on a game-object also called `A` and init all the variable in the Inspector.
Now, I have another `game-object B`, I want to pass the A script to the game-object `B` without init the variable in another script.
I tried `AddComponent()`, But it just add a script, I must init all the variable again. But I didn't want to init all the variable again. How can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your game object B, you create a new script with A as a parameter:

```
class B : MonoBehaviour
{
    public A AObject;

    void Update()
    {
        // Do something with A
        if (AObject.hasPancakes) { ... }
    }
}
```

Now, simply drag GameObject A onto this parameter in the scane inspector.

Refer to Accessing Other Objects in the Unity [docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ControllingGameObjectsComponents.html).

Update:

Like @joreldraw says, you can from script find the object A in the scene and save it:

```
AObject = Find("MyAObjectName").GetComponent<A>();
```

But, if you intent is to "clone" component A so you have a copy, one way is to clone the whole game object:

```
GameObject CopyOfA = Instantiate(AObject);
```

You now have a full copy of the whole game object.

Comment: Thanks, It works. But actually it don't meet my problem. I want to do that in script, not in the Editor. On the other handle, maybe I will destroy my object A, so that ,the AObject will be null

Comment: To do on script you need to tag your gameobject and use this:
    A = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ATaggedObject");
Other posibility is to know the hierachy or parent position or using a publc transform to link this and use.
   public transform Aroot; //Link on editor your root 
    A = Aroot.FindChild("MyAObjectName").GetComponent<AObject>();

Comment: I've updated the answer with how to clone a gameobject (and all components on it).

Comment: Thanks, At last, I choose your suggestion to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Unity do not offer `CopyComponent` functionality at runtime. For this case you need to interact with `System.Reflection` namespace and get a copy of your required component and add it to the current gameObject's component. Here is [an example](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/530178/how-to-get-a-component-from-an-object-and-add-it-t.html) using reflection.

Sample Code:

```
public class B : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        var script = this.gameObject.AddComponent<A> ();
        MyExtension.GetCopyOf (script, GameObject.Find ("A").GetComponent<A> ());
    }
}    

public static class MyExtension
{
    public static T GetCopyOf<T> (this Component comp, T other) where T : Component
    {
        Type type = comp.GetType ();
        if (type != other.GetType ())
            return null; // type mis-match
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;
        PropertyInfo[] pinfos = type.GetProperties (flags);
        foreach (var pinfo in pinfos) {
            if (pinfo.CanWrite) {
                try {
                    pinfo.SetValue (comp, pinfo.GetValue (other, null), null);
                } catch {
                } // In case of NotImplementedException being thrown. For some reason specifying that exception didn't seem to catch it, so I didn't catch anything specific.
            }
        }
        FieldInfo[] finfos = type.GetFields (flags);
        foreach (var finfo in finfos) {
            finfo.SetValue (comp, finfo.GetValue (other));
        }
        return comp as T;
    }
}
```

Here `MyExtension` is an extension class where `GetCopyOf` function is written.

Comment: Thank you very much. My friend said, reflection is not supported by IOS, Is it something related with this?

Comment: Yes this was a discussion in past: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/362219/how-can-i-use-reflection-in-ios.html but i just did a quick test using Unity 5.0.1f1 and Xcode 6.3 it is working with out any issue.

Comment: From your recent comment, it looks you want to keep your script alive. An advice for that case would be to attach this script on a separate game object try `DontDestroyOnLoad` and whenever needed access the script from that gameObject. So you will be saving copy effort each time.

Comment: yes, i opened your example and test just now. It works. But it lead to another problem. I dont know whether you can help me . I add '[RequireComponent(typeof(C))]' before My defintion for class A. like this '[RequireComponent(typeof(C))]
public class A'. C also have a lot of variable init in the inspector. Once I use your solution, I find class C is added to object B automatically. the variable in class C is the 0, not the value I set in object A

Comment: I am studying System.Reflection, maybe i can find something helpful

Comment: Ok Hold on C for just a minute, but does it copy the A's value to B ? Also have you seen my suggestion in the third comment ?

Answer (score 0):

From your query what I understood is that maybe you want to copy component from object A and paste it with values to another object B as you mention to init values in inspector. This can be done through ediotr scripts. To copy component from one gameobject to another with values, you may use EditorUtility.CopySerialized. I can provide example of an animation component, same can be used for any component

```
Animation srcAnimComponent = srcObjectA.GetComponent<Animation>();//this will get the source component with all the values or data from A
Animation destAnimComponent =  destObjectB.AddComponent<Animation>();//this will add the empty component to B
EditorUtility.CopySerialized(srcAnimComp, destAnimComp);//this will copy all the vaules from A comp to B comp
```

and later on destroy source component on A if move was the intention.